# What's the difference between доброе, добрый and доброй?

Tags: узус, word

Also, is there a difference between "спокойной ночи" and "доброй ночи"?

Comment: related (if not a duplicate) to - https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2694/why-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE-but-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C/2800

Comment: You ask one question int the title and one completely different int he body. What is your actual question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because exactly for reasons @Abakan provided

Comment: "доброй ночи" is in my experience an obsolete and awkward form, coming from XIX century and earlier literature. However is it more generic, than "спокойной". Say, you friend goes to allnighter party. Suggesting him "calm night" would be like "be loner in that party" or something. While "have a good night" might be seen as living him to decide what "good" means for him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we wish before going to bed is **спокойной ночи** (good night but to be precise "quiet night"). **Доброй ночи** ("kind " meaning "good and quiet ") is the same, but to my mind sounds poetically. But perhaps it's personal.
The phrase is an abbreviation from

> Я желаю вам/тебе спокойной/доброй ночи.

So желаю (чего?)+ **genitive case** (добрая ночь nominative – доброй ночи genitive).

Comment: **Доброй ночи** can also be used as a greeting or a goodbye (`Доброй ночи, до аэропорта довезёте?` or `Я пошёл домой, доброй ночи!`) while **спокойной ночи** rather not.

Answer (score 3):

usage of `Добрый` and `Доброе` depends on the gender of the noun, which this adjective agrees to. For example `Утро` is of neutral gender (`Оно моё утро`), so we should use `Доброе`, but `День` is of masculine gender (`Он мой день`), so we use `Добрый`. `Доброй` is slightly more complicated, as V.V. already stated, it is in genitive case with feminine noun. To summarize, please take a look at this table

```
           | Masculine | Feminine | Neutral |
Nominative |  Добрый   |  Добрая  | Доброе  |
Genitive   |  Доброго  |  Доброй  | Доброго |
```

I should note, that usage of `Доброго дня`, `Доброго вечера` is allowed, but `Добрая ночь` is incorrect